# Do I Have to Cash Out?

Tags: mtgox

Say I have an account with MtGox, and I put $5k worth of bitcoins in there. The exchange rate subsequently goes up by 10%. Now my MtGox bitcoins are worth 5.5k. Can I exchange this for USD in my MtGox account, but let it sit in my MtGox account until I want to buy bitcoins again?

The reason I ask is because I am in Australia, and MtGox charges a $10 fee (plus the 0.6%) to send to my bank account, and more importantly, it takes a few days to transfer. This means if I choose to buy BTC again, I have to transfer money from my bank account back into my MtGox account which also takes a few days. That's a turnaround time of almost a week, which would make "day trading" impossible!

Can I have usd in my MtGox account without transferring it to my bank account, or having it in bitcoins?

I'm a newbie, obviously...

Comment: "Can I have usd in my MtGox account without transferring it to my bank account, or having it in bitcoins?" Yep.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You should have put it in an answer if you want it to be accepted though. :)

Comment: Use two factor auth. its never smart to leave large sums of money in exchanges, especially without this.

Comment: @MaxSan you mean so nobody can log in as me and steal it?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Mtgox will not be responsible as many have found out for your lack of security.

Comment: Will MtGox then be responsible for it's own lack of security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I have usd in my MtGox account without transferring it to my bank account, or having it in bitcoins?

Yep.